# checking if number value is within an object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm trying to map each number in the array as a key to the empty object, and set the value as the index. However, the first index, 0, gets skipped...?

```
function solve(nums) {

    let obj = {};
    for (let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (!obj[nums[i]]) {  // if key does not exist, set key/value pair 
            obj[nums[i]] = i
        } else if (obj[nums[i]]) {
            obj[nums[i]] = 0  // if key exists, set to 0 
        }

    }

    console.log(obj)
}
solve([50, 30, 50, 90, 10])
```

Comment: It does not get skipped. You pass `50` two time but Object can not have two same properties.

Comment: Why do you set it to zero if you already seen it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Map` instead. Something like this:

```
function solve(nums) {
    let obj = new Map();
    for (let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (obj.get(nums[i]) == undefined) {  // if key does not exist, set key/value pair
            obj.set(nums[i]) = i;
        } else {
            obj.set(nums[i], 0);  // if key exists, set to 0 
        }
    }
    console.log(obj);
}
solve([50, 30, 50, 90, 10]);
```

**UPDATE**

It seems what you really need is something different. I will try to explain it a bit better since you have 2 numbers having the same value `50` and the only thing that's unique is the index, then you could have the index as the key, but also, you could need just one value and having both indexes as a value.

**For the first option you could use this:**

```
function solve(nums) {
    let obj = new Map();
    for (let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        obj.set(i,nums[i]);
    }
    console.log(obj);
}
solve([50, 30, 50, 90, 10]);
```

**For the second option this would be the code:**

```
function solve(nums) {
    let obj = new Map();
    for (let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (obj.get(nums[i]) == undefined) {  // if key does not exist, set key/value pair 
            obj.set(nums[i]) = i;
        } else {
            obj.set(nums[i], obj.get(nums[i]) + ',' + i);  // if key exists, append the second index 
        }
    }
    console.log(obj);
}
solve([50, 30, 50, 90, 10]);
```

Comment: @Seb using `Map` as @Juan suggests will allow you to use couple of `50`'s 

Comment: this doesn't work. copy and pasted and got error.

Comment: further more, it still does not catch the second value 50, and set it to 0...

Comment: @Seb I tried to improve my answer to fit your needs, but if what you need isn't the 3 options I posted, then you should edit your question and show a sample of what you need as an output

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok. It does not get skipped. You pass `50` two time but `Object` can not have two same properties. So second `50` is overriding the first `value`.

When you call `solve([500, 30, 50, 90, 10])`

You will get `{10: 4 30: 1 50: 2 90: 3 500: 0}`
Which is expected result.

Comment: ok, so how can i get it not to over ride the first result?

Comment: Use `Map` instead of `Object`. The @Juan's answer below.

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: @Seb you need to be more clear about what do you want to achieve ‍♂️ Your `else if` is overriding the property in your example in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am confused a bit with `else if` block, why you set it to `0`, if you find same number again.

But it is skipped, because you have `50` two times in your array. And when you loop through nums, when you get to index `i = 2`, you will have in object `{ 50: 0, 30: 1}`.

And because of that, `!0` returns `true`, so you will get again in `if` block, and you will override your value for key `50` with `2`.

Try with an array with 5 different values and it will work as you expect it